# Sólo me valida el último campo con Data annotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, razor, entity-framework-6

Tengo un formulario hecho con MVC. Uso Entity framework para la persistencia y para validar, Data Annotations.
Creo que la codificación esta bien, pero sólo me aparece el mensaje de la validación en el último campo, en este caso duración. Qu está pasando?

Controlador:

```
// GET: Peliculas/NuevoPelicula
        public ActionResult NuevoPelicula()
        {

            //var peli = new Pelicula();



            // return View(peli); 

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult NuevoPelicula(FormCollection form)
        {
            Context ctx = new Context();
            Peliculas pel = new Peliculas();

            pel.Nombre = form["nombre"];
            pel.Descripcion = form["descripcion"];
            pel.IdCalificacion = Convert.ToInt32(form["IdCalificacion"]);
            pel.IdGenero = Convert.ToInt32(form["IdGenero"]);
            pel.Imagen = form["imagen"];
            pel.Duracion = Convert.ToInt16(form["duracion"]);
            pel.FechaCarga = DateTime.Now;

            ctx.Peliculas.Add(pel);
            ctx.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Peliculas"); // Retorna a la vista "Peliculas"
        }
```

Vista:

```
@model Cinemania.Peliculas

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>NuevoPelicula</title>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Menu -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CINEMANIA</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Administracion</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Cerrar Sesion</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        @*using (Html.BeginForm("/NuevoPelicula", "Administracion", new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "text-danger" }))*@

        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {

            <div id="loginbox" class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">

                <!-- CABECERA -->
                <h2 class="text-center">Nuevo</h2>

                <!-- INPUT NOMBRE -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Nombre">Nombre</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nombre, new { placeholder = "Ingresar Nombre", @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nombre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

                <!-- INPUT DESCRIPCION -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="descripcion">Descripcion</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Descripcion, new { placeholder = "Ingresar Descripcion", @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Descripcion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

                <!-- INPUT CALIFICACION -->
                <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="IdCalificacion">Calificacion</label>
                    <select>
                        <option value="ATP">ATP</option>

                        <option value="May13">May13</option>
                        <option value="May13R">May13R</option>

                        <option value="May16">May16</option>
                        <option value="May16R">May16R</option>

                    </select>
                    @*Html.DropDownList("IdCalificacion", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag["IdCalificacion"], "Selecione genero", new { @class = "form-control" }) *@

                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdCalificacion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                </div>

                <!-- INPUT GENERO -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="IdGenero">Genero</label>
                    <select>
                        <option value="Terror">Terror</option>
                        <option value="Thriller">Thriller</option>
                        <option value="Accion">Accion</option>
                        <option value="Comedia">Comedia</option>
                        <option value="ComediaR">ComediaR</option>
                    </select>

                    @*Html.DropDownList("IdGenero", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag["IdGenero"], "Selecione calificacion", new { @class = "form-control" })*@

                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdGenero, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>





                <!-- INPUT IMAGEN -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Imagen">Imagen</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Imagen, new { Type = "file" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Imagen, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>


                <!-- INPUT DURACION -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Duracion">Duracion</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Duracion, new { placeholder = "Ingresar Duracion", @class = "form-control" })




                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Duracion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

                <!-- BOTON GUARDAR -->
                <div class="text-center">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Guardar" />

                    <!-- LINK SALIR -->
                    <a href="./Peliculas" class="btn btn-default">Cancelar</a>
                </div>



            </div>}
    </div>


    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Modelo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Cinemania.Models;

namespace Cinemania.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(PeliculaMetadata))]
    public partial class Pelicula
    {

    }    
}
```

//metadata para la validación

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Cinemania.Models
{
    public class PeliculaMetadata
    {
        [Required]      
        public int cod { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(150, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage = " El {0} debe tener entre 10 y 50 caracteres")]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        [Required]    
        public string Calificacion { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Genero { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Duracion { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

debes usar una vista fuertemente tipada a un objeto osea:

controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NuevoPelicula(Pelicula pelicula)
    {

        Context ctx = new Context();     

        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {       
        pel.FechaCarga = DateTime.Now;

        ctx.Peliculas.Add(pelicula);
        ctx.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Peliculas"); // Retorna a la vista "Peliculas"
       }
       //aqui retornas todo lo que tenias en el create con método get
    }
```

y en tu vista:

```
@model Cinemania.Peliculas
<div class="container">       

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div id="loginbox" class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">

            <!-- CABECERA -->
            <h2 class="text-center">Nuevo</h2>

            <!-- INPUT NOMBRE -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Nombre">Nombre</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nombre, new { placeholder = "Ingresar Nombre", @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nombre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <!-- INPUT DESCRIPCION -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="descripcion">Descripcion</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Descripcion, new { placeholder = "Ingresar Descripcion", @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Descripcion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <!-- INPUT CALIFICACION -->
            <div class="form-group">

                <label for="IdCalificacion">Calificacion</label>
                <select>
                    <option value="ATP">ATP</option>

                    <option value="May13">May13</option>
                    <option value="May13R">May13R</option>

                    <option value="May16">May16</option>
                    <option value="May16R">May16R</option>

                </select>
                @*Html.DropDownList("IdCalificacion", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag["IdCalificacion"], "Selecione genero", new { @class = "form-control" }) *@

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdCalificacion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>

            <!-- INPUT GENERO -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="IdGenero">Genero</label>
                <select>
                    <option value="Terror">Terror</option>
                    <option value="Thriller">Thriller</option>
                    <option value="Accion">Accion</option>
                    <option value="Comedia">Comedia</option>
                    <option value="ComediaR">ComediaR</option>
                </select>

                @*Html.DropDownList("IdGenero", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag["IdGenero"], "Selecione calificacion", new { @class = "form-control" })*@

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdGenero, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>





            <!-- INPUT IMAGEN -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Imagen">Imagen</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Imagen, new { Type = "file" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Imagen, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>


            <!-- INPUT DURACION -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Duracion">Duracion</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Duracion, new { placeholder = "Ingresar Duracion", @class = "form-control" })




                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Duracion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <!-- BOTON GUARDAR -->
            <div class="text-center">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Guardar" />

                <!-- LINK SALIR -->
                <a href="./Peliculas" class="btn btn-default">Cancelar</a>
            </div>



        </div>}
</div>
```

con eso tu controlador espera un objeto de tipo película con sus respectivos parámetros para validar, de no ser válido te retorna la vista con los errores

Comment: el controller posee errores, por ejemplo dice que pel no existe

Comment: elproblema es que las validaciones se las agregas al modelo con DataAnnotations, pero no estas recogiendo un modelo en tu post. debes recoger un modelo de tipo película para que se apliquen las validaciones con el metodo .IsValid de lo contrario no sabe qué esta validando

Comment: entonces como hago?

Comment: también te faltó agregar la linea @Html.ValidationSummary(true) en el formulario

Comment: le agrego eso y sigue igual